# Print variable inside awk while calculating variable name

Tags: bash, awk, ksh

I have a script that looks like the example below. I have a letter offset and I need to print the letter that I calculate with the offset.  I am not sure how to read that letter using ksh.

My expected answer would be for LETTER_OFFSET(1)=a,LETTER_OFFSET(2)=v, LETTER_OFFSET(3)=c, etc. The offset I have it been calculated inside a loop.

```
#!/bin/ksh
#         1    2  3  4  5  6  7 8  9 10  11 12
LETTERS=" a    v  c  d  g  r  g s  s a   g   f"
LETTER_OFFSET="3";
Letter=$(echo $LETTERS | awk '{print $((1 * $$LETTER_OFFSET )) }')
```

Comment: Please refrain from adding any sort of txtspk to your posts here. In addition, you don't need to add "please help" or similar fluff. Readers know you would like some help, so material of that kind may be read as a form of pleading. Keep it succinct if you can.

Comment: awk is not shell so don't assume you can use shell variables and syntax within an awk script. Treat an awk program like you would a C program - something you can call from shell but is not shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll pass your offset into your awk script to use as an awk variable using the awk -v flag:

```
LETTER=$(echo $LETTERS | awk -v offset=$LETTER_OFFSET '{print $offset}')
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to invoke `awk` in every iteration. You can populate an array using your letters and then access it's values using `index`:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#         1    2  3  4  5  6  7 8  9 10  11 12
letters=" a    v  c  d  g  r  g s  s a   g   f"

# populate an array
arr=($letters)

offset=1
while [ "$offset" -le 12 ]; do
   echo "${arr[$offset-1]}"
   let offset++
done
```

**Output:**

```
a
v
c
d
g
r
g
s
s
a
g
f
```